# Name 直人 pitch accent

Tags: names, pitch-accent

Since 菅直人さん's name did come up in the news a lot, I thought I was pretty familiar with the pronunciation which I thought was なおと{HLL} but I seem to have heard this name (not 菅直人さん, other 直人s) pronounced なおと{LHH} or なおと{LHL} and I'm wondering if I misheard them. Is [this](https://youtu.be/em66npmgOM0?t=10) なおと{LHL}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's definitely なおと{HLL} to me. But I have to agree with you that the phonetic pitch peak resides in the mora お in your clip (遅下がり). It seems that the third one's あさひ{HLL} also exhibits a similar trait in a less significant degree (by the way, I hear the second name せいや{LHH} but this word as a name is expected to be せいや{HLL} in Tokyo and I don't know whether it is an articulation issue).

Nevertheless, it is still distinguishable from なおと{LHL}. The research of 遅下がり is still immature as far as I know so the answer is quite subjective, but in this case, true なおと{LHL} should have consistently high if not upward (and strong) mora お, where in your video お was only high at the beginning but dropping afterward (not intentionally in falling tone but like losing power "ohhhh..."), which suggests that the high point is only the residue of an accent that should have fallen on the previous mora.